# Not found HandBrakeCLI exe

Tags: c#, dll, mp4, handbrake

i work on HandBrake open source project. it need to **HandBrakeCLI.exe** file..

I search google long time but not found.

in **Program** file and **Main** method this line:

```
if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "HandBrakeCLI.exe")))
{
    missingFiles += "\"HandBrakeCLI.exe\" was not found.";
}
```

note : this source download from github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the information that you gave... IF you want the command prompt file you can get it here : https://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php 
And if you want to run the file you can get help here : https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/cli/cli-options.html

The file should be in the directory where you extracted handbrake. And you run it via command prompt from the extracted directory.

Comment: i see ...but  this is not my point.. i need "HandBrakeCLI.exe".. ..read my question

Comment: Hope I understand you correctly, The code goes into the if statement and displays  "HandBrakeCLI.exe" was not found. If that is the case then firstly you need to get the "HandBrakeCLI.exe" witch you can get in the zip file : https://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php Then take HandBrakeCLI.exe and put it in you application folder. Where the application runs from. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Normally Visual studio creates a debug or a release folder where it runs from in your projects that you run. Try copying HandBrakeCLI.exe into that folder and run it.

Comment: The path of your project is normally here :Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug where WindowsFormsApplication1 is your application

Comment: Tanks ;) worked

Comment: So it depends how you are running your application